# Magento 2.4.6 - Main menu per category

Tags: topmenu, magento2.4.6

Good day,
We want to create better menu navigation for our customers in our Magento 2.4.6 shop. Our shop specializes in aftermarket suspension for vehicles in the “tuning” and “off-road” categories. In these two main categories there are further differences in chassis and accessories.

I was thinking of a menu that is displayed by default, in this case the "Tuning" menu with an "Offroad" button on the right to get to the associated category and its subcategories

Is there an easy way to set menus by category or is there an extension known here?